# Flip animation of tableview with its own TableViewController within main ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, animation, view

Relatively basic issue, but I spent whole day figuring out without any success. I have ViewController with main fullscreen View and separate TableViewController with TableView which does not cover the entire screen. I need to use UIRefreshControl on the TableView, hence the separate TVC.

I want to achieve that on cell selection existing TableView will flip around to be replaced with another TableView (like a step 2 of user selection). I expect that the existing main View will be visible during the TableViews transition.

I was able to achieve the full View flip transiton into different view using the begin animation/commit animation method, but never the childview only, nor using the new animation block method. Can you please suggest the animation code and how should I introduce the second tableview (under the existing TVC or under it's own TVC)?

```
@implementation ViewController
TableViewController *tableVC;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    tableVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableVC"];
    [self addChildViewController:tableVC];
    tableVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(8, 177, 304, 371);
    [self.view addSubview:tableVC.view];
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: You need to pass tableView in parameter in animation method called. Parameter name is like forView pass tableView in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this Sample code it might help you

https://github.com/GrioSF/spincard

Comment: I can't figure out where to put the forView parameter, however using the sample code provided I resolved the issue. I add both subViews and change the hidden parameter during animation as in the Sample. Many thanks!

Comment: in the [UIView animation] function call you need to put table view as in demo sample card is passed in parameter. see demo code again